# Should the [resource] tag be split

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-disambiguation

[[resources]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resources) has this [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/resources/info):

> > Assets (like memory, disk space, CPU power or alike) necessary for effective operation **or** physical files (like images, configuration files or other) to provide some externalized enrichment to an application.
>
> Typically resources are materials or other assets that are transformed to produce benefit and in the process may be consumed or made unavailable

which includes a computer's assets as well as files. These are two different things. A person asking how to create an app to display system resources is not asking about files, and a person asking how to include a bitmap in their app is not asking about memory usage. In the world of computers resources means two *different* things; resource is a homograph in this sense.

I would split them into `[resources]` (for files) and a new tag `[system-resources]` (for CPU, memory, IO, etc.). Most of these tagged questions are related to files, and not system resources.